# MyBatis n+1 problem but only with annotations

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, mybatis

## I *have*:

## Two (POSTGRES) tables

- question table
- skill table

each question can have 1 - 5 skills (1:n)

Example:

1. **Question** Table

| id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | How to multiply | I want to multiply 2 and 3 ... |
| 2 | How to bake a cake | I want to bake a chocolate ... |

2. **Skill** Table

| id | question_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mathematics |
| 2 | 1 | numbers |
| 3 | 2 | baking |
| 4 | 2 | chocolate |
| 5 | 2 | melting |

## a Pojo

Question, like:

```
data class Question(
val id: Long,
val title: String,
val content: String,
val skillNames: Set<String>,
) {
    @Suppress("unused") // needed for QuestionMapper#getQuestions
    constructor(
        id: Long,
        title: String,
        userId: String,
        skillNames: Set<String>
    ) : this(id, title, userId, setOf())
}
```

## two queries

SkillMapper:

```
@Suppress("unused") // needed for QuestionMapper#getQuestions
@Select(
    """
        SELECT 
            name
        FROM 
           skill
        WHERE 
            question_id = #{questionId}
    """
)
fun getSkillNamesForQuestionId(@Param("questionId") questionId: Long): Set<String>
```

QuestionMapper

```
@Select(
    """
        SELECT
            q.id,
            q.title,
            q.content
        FROM
            question q
    """
)
@Results(
    value = [
        Result(
            property = "skillIds",
            javaType = Set::class,
            column = "id",
            many = Many(
                select = "SkillMapper.getSkillNamesForQuestionId"
            )
        )
    ]
)
fun getQuestions(): List<Question>
```

## I can

fetch all questions and their linked skills with this. Unfortunately this means for every question one extra query is executed to fetch the skill-names (N+1 Problem).

## I want

to use [MyBatis Nested select for collection](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#nested-select-for-collection) **but** with annotations only (no xml).

## Question

Does anyone know how I can use nested results, but with annotations only?

in detail:
I want to use:

```
<resultMap id="blogResult" type="Blog">
  <collection property="posts" javaType="ArrayList" column="id" ofType="Post" select="selectPostsForBlog"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectBlog" resultMap="blogResult">
  SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>

<select id="selectPostsForBlog" resultType="Post">
  SELECT * FROM POST WHERE BLOG_ID = #{id}
</select>
```

But I don't know how to define a Result Map *with* annotations. There is an annotation `@ResultMap` but it seems this is only used to refer to a ResultMap (not for defining one)

Comment: Write a custom DTO (`QuestionWithSkills`) and a query with a JOIN to return those objects.

Comment: how will duplicates be handled? if I do that, question with `id=1` will occur two times and question with `id=2` will occur three times in the result set (for each skill).

Comment: That depends on the type of SQL JOIN you use. There are left, right and inner joins, and each will give different results.

Comment: but I want to fetch every question, with every linked (to each question) skillname ...

Comment: @SleepyX667 This [test case](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/5d51f64b9cf81f73c235b79fcd2ca17e089728df/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/annotion_many_one_add_columnprefix/UserDao.java#L30-L42) demonstrates how to map "nested results" using annotations. Note that you need to use a recent version of MyBatis (3.5.5+, the latest is 3.5.13).